Animated film featuring a one-wheeled motorbike equipped with rockets
I'm trying to find an animated film that has a one-wheeled motorbike.
From what I can remember later in the film and the battle scenes at the end, the main character is on a bike with one big wheel at the back and kind of like a roof going over him with rockets of the side, all to fight something big and mechanical at the end. 
At the start of the last fight he starts out with a group helping take down the bigger vehicles, then ends up fighting that last one on his own.
I think towards the end of the fight, he ends up going almost vertical up some maybe ruins of a road that was supported by pillars, and it tried to follow but couldn't and either flipped or started sliding back down, after which he turns around goes down and destroys it.
I think the main character raced a one-wheeled vehicle in the beginning, then the fighting started and he then used something similar but with rockets.
I think it was made around 2000, possibly from Japan. Time is set to post apocalyptic or at least during a war, it was in color. The bike, imagine a motorbike, take off the front wheel and incrase the back maybe 3x. With rockets above where the front one wheel is supposed to be.
All of this is what I think I can remember some points may vary slightly but I don't think too much.

It's maybe a long shot and also a bit older, but possibly Venus Senki (Venus Wars) from Japan, 1989. 
Synopsis:

The new frontier of Venus has degenerated into a dystopia ravaged by the civil war between Ishtar and Aphrodia. Bubbly reporter Susan Sommers arrives in the capitol of Aphrodia just before it's captured by Ishtar. She falls in with a bunch of teen-agers who live for a sort of motorcycle version of Roller Derby. Daredevil rider Hiro and his friends reluctantly join the struggle to free Aphrodia from the invaders. Not surprisingly, Hiro proves an ace at piloting the mono-cycles that are the Aphrodians' secret weapon in the key battle.

From Wikipedia:

The Venus Wars film was localized in the United Kingdom and the United States by Manga Entertainment and Central Park Media respectively, gaining recognition when it aired in heavy rotation on the Sci-Fi Channel "Saturday Anime" movie block in the late 1990s.

Trailer:


 
Features many armed mono-wheeled vehicles, one of them (00:45 mark) seems to fit your description.
Movie (Japanese, no subtitles):




this was it indeed thanks epic film thanks

@sn1peme If this is the movie you are looking, you can click on the tick mark near the answer which means the question is solved.
